# Как разбить данную строку на массив слов без знаков пунктуации?

Tags: java, массивы, регулярные-выражения, строки

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Test 2: splitWords");
        String text = "   ,, first, second!!!! third";
        String[] splitResult = text.split("\\W+");
        System.out.println("Result : " + Arrays.toString(splitResult));
        String[] expectedSplit = new String[]{"first", "second", "third"};
        System.out.println("Must be: " + Arrays.toString(expectedSplit));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что исходная строка может содержать разделители *перед первым* и *после последнего* слова, вследствие чего такие разделители приведут к генерации пустых строк после `split`.

Для решения этого можно либо обработать исходную строку и удалить разделители в её начале и конце, и потом выполнять разбиение:

```java
String[] splitResult = text.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$", "").split("\\W+");
```

либо удалить пустые строки *из промежуточного списка*:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\\W+")));
list.removeIf(String::isEmpty);
String[] splitResult = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

либо отфильтровать пустые строки, используя Stream API:

```java
String[] splitResult = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\W+"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

---

Также следует отметить, что для разбиения по не-буквам всех алфавитов, а не только английского, следует использовать [класс символов `"\\P{L}+"` для работы с Unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) вместо `"\\W+"`:

```java
String text = "   !! Aзъ Буки Вѣди !! ";        
String[] splitResult = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\P{L}+"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .toArray(String[]::new);
// -> [Aзъ, Буки, Вѣди]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось! )))